# What alternatives are there to modelling complex behaviour with finite state machines?

Tags: design-patterns, state-machine

I have read about a lot of disadvantages of using finite state machines but haven't really seen any alternative patterns for modelling complex behaviour suggested- are there any?

Comment: You asked a very similar, open-ended question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14471057/62576), and it was closed for being too vague. This one is entirely too vague as well; it asks for discussion. Please do your own research, and then come back here with **specific** questions. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has more information about the types of questions to ask here, and some suggestions on how to write better questions when you have a specific one. Good luck.

Comment: Wow discussions are not bad things. What makes this a vague question? You are right there will not be one simple answer like 'here do this.' But in fact, his question does pose a simple, specific concrete query: what alternatives are there?

Comment: @Rob: The site guidelines. :-) This site is for **specific** questions, and the FAQ (linked in my previous comment) says definitively that discussion questions are a poor fit for the Q&A format of this site. There are other StackExchange sites for more generic discussions, like [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) for this type of question. (Also, if you have questions for a specific person, prefix their user name with `@`, as I did to get this comment to your Inbox.)

Comment: I did do research but could only find examples of trivial state machines.

Comment: @Ken yeah I have seen all that stuff. I personally think there's too much policing around here, but don't want to spend time debating that. Someone saying what other idioms or patterns are there is not vague in my book, and frankly, answers to questions like these are more likely to have lasting value.

Comment: @Rob: If you don't like the guidelines here, the appropriate place to voice that is [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). Don't complain to the users that vote to keep posts within the guidelines. :-) If you read the FAQ (again linked above), users who have earned sufficient rep to do so enforce the *existing site guidelines* to keep noise and clutter to a minimum to ensure that SO remains a useful resource. If you want to change the guidelines, meta is the place to ask for that change.

Answer (score 2):

Could you give us some references? I generally see FSMs written about in glowing terms. If you truly have an FSM, they are not that difficult to implement and they have a lot of advantages. A lot of times, though, people think they have an FSM, but what they really have is some simple procedural thing that proceeds through a few steps. If that's the case, then the key alternative to consider is the design pattern [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Where FSMs really shine, doing things above and beyond what could be done with Template Method, is when there are constraints about progression from one stage to another. For example, if we were modeling something like the preparation of a tax return, all the preliminary collection of earnings and the computation of gross wages is done in the first stage and there should be no way to start computing deductions until the wages are complete. (This is a contrived example, but imagine that there are other preconditions on state transitions.)

Template Method, per the example in the Gang of Four, makes it possible to enforce in an abstract class the fact that certain actions have to proceed through a sequence of steps, in order. The interesting thing about Template Method is that you are hiding those details and forcing the subclasser to simply provide implementations of the required steps/methods.